# In Python, how can I map column value in Table 1 to another Table 2 and append back to Table 1?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a table with a list of currencies as column in df1['Ccy]

```
   Ccy    
0   GBP           
1   GBP        
2   USD       
3   EUR
4   GBP
5   USD
```

I have a second table that has values, df2:

```
    Ccy FX Rate
0   USD 0.750244
1   JPY 0.007196
2   GBP 1.000000
3   EUR 0.893390
```

How can I create a mapping as a new column in df1 that has the FX Rate column values per respective currency, e.g:

```
  Ccy       FX Rate
0   GBP     1.000000
1   GBP     1.000000   
2   USD     0.750244  
3   EUR     0.893390
4   GBP     1.000000   
5   USD     0.750244
```

I could do a mapping like the below but it replaces original currencies rather than creates a new column with the mapped numerical values:
rename_dict = df2.set_index('Ccy').to_dict()['FX Rate']
df1 = df1.replace(rename_dict)

Want to simply add the mappings as a new column to the original df1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [merge two dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on "Ccy".

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Ccy",how="left")
```